# Cable layout for multiple motors and encoders

Tags: dc-motor, cables, cable-assemblies, rotary-encoder

I need to make a connection between 2 PCBs, the first is a controller board with microcontroller, motor drivers and other peripherals. The second is a motor/encoder board, essentially a three motor version of [this](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/magnetic-encoder-pair-kit-for-micro-metal-gearmotors-12-cpr-2-7-18v-hpcb-compatible?variant=30271550914643). The distance between the 2 boards is about 100mm.

I can choose the connectors to go on each board.
How should I layout the cable/s to go between the boards?

The single encoder board linked above lays the connection out as: M1, M2, VCC, EncA, EncB, GND

Other motor assemblies (e.g. faulhaber) have the connections as: M1, VCC, EncA, EncB, GND, M2

Should I keep the motor encoders together so have 3 connectors with 6 pins and use one of the above layouts or would it be better to seperate according to the signals?

For example have a 6 pin connector with all motor connections and then an 8 pin connector with power and the encoder signals.